Javafx failing to launch on M3 chip, 'AssertionFailure' Error cannot solve
Have tried running a javafx program on my mac, and have been treated to this error:
Oct 26, 2024 7:54:11 AM com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacApplication lambda$waitForReactivation$6
WARNING: Timeout while waiting for app reactivation
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '0x0 is an invalid NSTrackingRectTag. Common possible reasons for this are: 1. already removed this trackingRectTag, 2. Truncated the NSTrackingRectTag to 32bit at some point.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182998ec0 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018247ecd8 objc_exception_throw + 88
    2   Foundation                          0x0000000183b95588 -[NSCalendarDate initWithCoder:] + 0
    3   AppKit                              0x0000000186c8d7c4 -[_NSTrackingAreaAKViewHelper removeTrackingRect:] + 200
    4   libglass.dylib                      0x0000000111e5ef7c Java_com_sun_glass_ui_mac_MacApplication__1getMacKey + 3456
    5   libglass.dylib                      0x0000000111e64074 RemoteLayerHostRemoteIdInLocal + 3620
    6   AppKit                              0x00000001864a186c -[NSView setFrame:] + 304
    7   libglass.dylib                      0x0000000111e640d4 RemoteLayerHostRemoteIdInLocal + 3716
    8   AppKit                              0x00000001864ae2a4 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 488
    9   AppKit                              0x00000001864adc30 -[NSView resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 360
    10  AppKit                              0x0000000186494074 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 948
    11  AppKit                              0x00000001864a186c -[NSView setFrame:] + 304
    12  AppKit                              0x00000001864ae2a4 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 488
    13  AppKit                              0x00000001864adc30 -[NSView resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 360
    14  AppKit                              0x0000000186494074 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 948
    15  AppKit                              0x00000001864ace0c -[NSThemeFrame setFrameSize:] + 244
    16  AppKit                              0x00000001864ac768 -[NSWindow _oldPlaceWindow:fromServer:] + 532
    17  AppKit                              0x00000001864abc1c -[NSWindow _setFrameCommon:display:fromServer:] + 1984
    18  libglass.dylib                      0x0000000111e6f0c4 Java_com_sun_glass_ui_mac_MacWindow__1setBounds2 + 416
    19  ???                                 0x000000013fd3cfd4 0x0 + 5365813204
    20  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    21  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    22  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    23  ???                                 0x000000013fd396b0 0x0 + 5365798576
    24  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    25  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    26  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    27  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    28  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    29  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    30  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    31  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    32  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    33  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    34  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    35  ???                                 0x000000013fd396b0 0x0 + 5365798576
    36  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    37  ???                                 0x000000013fd396b0 0x0 + 5365798576
    38  ???                                 0x000000013fd38ea0 0x0 + 5365796512
    39  ???                                 0x000000013fd39440 0x0 + 5365797952
    40  ???                                 0x000000013fd38ea0 0x0 + 5365796512
    41  ???                                 0x000000013fd38ea0 0x0 + 5365796512
    42  ???                                 0x000000013fd39110 0x0 + 5365797136
    43  ???                                 0x000000013fd396b0 0x0 + 5365798576
    44  ???                                 0x000000013fd34114 0x0 + 5365776660
    45  libjvm.dylib                        0x0000000102364764 _ZN9JavaCalls11call_helperEP9JavaValueRK12methodHandleP17JavaCallArgumentsP10JavaThread + 984
    46  libjvm.dylib                        0x00000001023d575c _ZL20jni_invoke_nonstaticP7JNIEnv_P9JavaValueP8_jobject11JNICallTypeP10_jmethodIDP18JNI_ArgumentPusherP10JavaThread + 992
    47  libjvm.dylib                        0x00000001023da184 jni_CallVoidMethod + 284
    48  libglass.dylib                      0x0000000111e5a998 JNI_OnLoad + 204
    49  Foundation                          0x0000000183b00b90 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 264
    50  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182926414 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
    51  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001829263a8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
    52  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018292610c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
    53  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182924cf8 __CFRunLoopRun + 840
    54  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182924334 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    55  HIToolbox                           0x000000018dd5d0cc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
    56  HIToolbox                           0x000000018dd62ebc ReceiveNextEventCommon + 636
    57  HIToolbox                           0x000000018dd63020 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
    58  AppKit                              0x0000000186468a70 _DPSNextEvent + 660
    59  AppKit                              0x0000000186d8e7b8 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 688
    60  AppKit                              0x000000018645bb7c -[NSApplication run] + 480
    61  libglass.dylib                      0x0000000111e5cb20 JNI_OnLoad + 8788
    62  Foundation                          0x0000000183b00b90 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 264
    63  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182926414 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
    64  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001829263a8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
    65  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018292610c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
    66  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182924cf8 __CFRunLoopRun + 840
    67  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182924334 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    68  libjli.dylib                        0x0000000100e10e84 CreateExecutionEnvironment + 404
    69  libjli.dylib                        0x0000000100e0c984 JLI_Launch + 1152
    70  java                                0x0000000100dc7bb0 main + 404
    71  dyld                                0x00000001824bc274 start + 2840
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException


I have just switched from a windows machine to a mac, I watched a guide to installing IntelliJ and Java and went to run my first javafx program on the mac and it failed.
I have tried researching this error but haven't yet found any fixes.
I am using Oracle OpenJDK 23.0.1, but have also used ones intellij automatically downloaded and they still don't work.
I am using Maven build script.
I also get this error stating, 'java quit unexpectedly' (Is very long so have provided a pastebin link containing the full details)
Error Report
Thanks!

Which version of macOS are you using? Which version of JavaFX? Looks like there were some incompatibilities with macOS 14 and some versions of JavaFX. See JavaFX window takes a while to load and getting an error in Eclipse and What does this error mean: com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacApplication lambda$waitForReactivation$6 WARNING: Timeout while waiting for app reactivation?.

You should also post your Maven POM.

The crash is probably a fixed bug JDK-8296654
macos aarch64 Crash when launching JavaFX app with JDK:

all JavaFX applications will start crashing when run on a JDK that is built with Xcode 14.1 + MacOSX SDK 13

The warning Timeout while waiting for app reactivation that you receive is also a fixed bug (which shows you are using an outdated JavaFX version not built to work with your Mac).

What does this error mean: com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacApplication lambda$waitForReactivation$6 WARNING: Timeout while waiting for app reactivation?


The solution, as noted by Slaw in the comments, is to use a recent JavaFX version (e.g. 23.0.1).
JavaFX can be downloaded in SDK form from Gluon, and instructions on use are at openjfx.io.
Or, as you are using Idea:

Create a new JavaFX project.

I recommend selecting Maven as the build system unless you favor Gradle.


Edit the JavaFX version in the project to 23.0.1

Don't use a version with an ea suffix which signifies early access.


Resynchronize the project with the IDE.

This can be done via the maven panel in the IDE.


Build and run your application as per the instructions in the new JavaFX project guide.

